# Exception:rg.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.mapping.DatastoreDataException: Unable to convert class PageRequest to Datastore

Tags: spring, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, gql

I have issue with Spring data. When I use @Query annotation with Pageable, for example:

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myTable.t_blob_name > NULL")
    Slice<MyTable> findAllWithPageable(Pageable pageable);
```

I will have next exception (That application runs on Google cloud platform):

```
org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.mapping.DatastoreDataException: Unable to convert class org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest to Datastore supported type.
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.convert.DatastoreNativeTypes.wrapValue (DatastoreNativeTypes.java:166)
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.core.convert.TwoStepsConversions.convertOnWriteSingle (TwoStepsConversions.java:320)
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository.query.GqlDatastoreQuery.bindArgsToGqlQuery (GqlDatastoreQuery.java:233)
at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository.query.GqlDatastoreQuery.execute (GqlDatastoreQuery.java:118)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke (RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3 (RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke (RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke (DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke (ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke (SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed (ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke (JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
```

It's a google cloud DataStore syntax and the main question - how to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list of supported classes that can be used within GQL. You can find it in [reference point 158.5.2](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RC1/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html) and directly in [code on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/data/datastore/core/convert/DatastoreNativeTypes.java) if you prefer. Actually the `Pageable` class is not among them.

I noticed that you are not using this paramater in the query so I suggest to use  `Slice<MyTable> findAllWithPageable()` Similar query you may find in [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query).

I hope it will help!